# Querying SharePoint List from Reporting Services returns only “not null” columns

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

Tried this link but does not display the columns which has null values.

[Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariae/archive/2007/12/13/querying-sharepoint-list-from-reporting-services-returns-only-not-null-columns.aspx)

Any Idea, whats being missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you have replaced the names of "Column1,Column2"... for the names of your fields from your Sharepoint list...

If so, make sure the field names you put there are the internal sharepoint list field names and not the display field names.

If the names have spaces, remember to use the *x0020* instead of the a space.

Also, make sure the fields are called with the prefix ows_, not just the field name...

I would try @ows_ID and see what happens and with the above everything still fails and data doesn't show, then there must be something else but we will need you to post the code here.